# Async functions using value from a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

So I know this question is asked a lot, but I'm trying to retrieve a variable that is created within a promise. The examples I've seen on here involve calling  .then and using the data there, however what I'm trying to do involves an async function--which i cant use within the .then block.

Here's my code. I'm using the Asana API To call out a lists of tasks that are due. It successfuly logs it. But I want to save the list value from the last block as a variable that I can use elsewhere.

```
const asana = require('asana');
        const client = asana.Client.create().useAccessToken("xxx");
      client.users.me()
        .then(user => {
            const userId = user.id;
            // The user's "default" workspace is the first one in the list, though
            // any user can have multiple workspaces so you can't always assume this
            // is the one you want to work with.
            const workspaceId = user.workspaces[0].id;
            return client.tasks.findAll({
              assignee: userId,
              workspace: workspaceId,
              completed_since: 'now',
              opt_fields: 'id,name,assignee_status,completed'
            });
          })
          .then(response => {
            // There may be more pages of data, we could stream or return a promise
            // to request those here - for now, let's just return the first page
            // of items.
            return response.data;
          })
          .filter(task => {
            return task.assignee_status === 'today' ||
              task.assignee_status === 'new';
          })
          .then(list => {
            console.log (util.inspect(list, {
              colors: true,
              depth: null
            }));







          })
          .catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
          });
```

Comment: I would think that the `.filter(task => {` would throw a `TypeError`, unless what comes before is a non-standard Promise? Regardless, everywhere that you want to use the final resolve value should go inside the final `.then`

Comment: Yes, @CertainPerformance , asana uses bluebird promises

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're open to rewriting your .then()'s as async/await something like this could work for you:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
async function doit() {
    const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
    const json = await response.json();
    console.log(json);
}
doit();
```

Comment: `const just = () => doit(); just();`